# Grep data from multiple file then feed into a log

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I want to grep data from multiple files then combine the data I grep into a single log.  My input files as such:

#### Input file1 (200MHz)

```
Cell_a  freq_100  50
Cell_a  freq_200  6.8
Cell_b  freq_100  70
```

#### Input file2 (100MHz)

```
Cell_a  freq_100  100
Cell_a  freq_200  10.5
Cell_b  freq_100  60
```

#### This is my expected output

```
<cell>  <freq> <value_frm__file2> <value_frm_file1> <etc>
```

#### Example expected output:-

```
Cell_a  freq_100 100 50
Cell_a  freq_200 10.5 6.8
Cell_b  freq_100 60 70
```

I only able to grep the value once in a time. Can someone help in solving this?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(switch say);

my %record;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($cell, $freq, $num) = split " ";

    push @{$record{$cell}->{$freq}}, $num;
}

while (my ($cell, $freqs) = each %record) {
    while (my ($freq, $nums) = each %$freqs) {
        say "$cell $freq ", join(" ", @$nums);
    }
}
```

---

Run it like this:

```
./t.pl input1.txt input2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much Duhem, for your prompt reply and yes! your codes just like a magic and solve my problem!!  I have one more problem which if each of the input file is having it's freq, how do I make sure the precedence in the num as if I want the num grep form the lowest freq input file to print first?  I modified my question to be precise.  Thanks!

Comment: @Grace I do not understand your additional question. You want those number in some order, or those frequences in some order?

Comment: The order of the num will need to base on the input file freq. Num of the lowest freq input file should be grepped first.  Example, the first input file1 is 200MHz and the second input file2 is 100MHz, hence the num from file2 should be the first vale appear within the line "Cell_a  freq_100 100 50".  Not "Cell_a  freq_100 50 100".  Hope that clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @Grace Could you not just change the positions of input1 and input2?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as actually I have >2 input files to process.  And each of them need to process according to the ascending sequence from lowest o highest.

Comment: @Grace You could change that `push` to `unshift`, this will reverse the order of the numbers add to the `@$nums` list.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate your help though the unshift isn't really works for me.  By the way, could you pls explain your above codes especially on the bottom part.         while (my ($cell, $freqs) = each %record) {
    while (my ($freq, $nums) = each %$freqs) {
        say "$cell $freq ", join(" ", @$nums);
    }
}

Comment: @Grace 1. `push` or `unshift`, one of them should work, if it does not, then you must have some untold assumptions or mistakes in your question description. 2. Which part of the code you does not understand? Maybe dump that `%record` will help you, add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%record);` at the end and give it a try.

Comment: I don't understand the while loops line #5 and #6 from the bottom.

Comment: @Grace Did you check the structure of `%record`? If you did, you will find out that `$freqs` is a hash reference, that is why I add `%` before it. Those two whiles just are the standard usage of `each`, no any fancy syntax, you could read its manual by `perldoc -f each`.

Comment: Thanks, but the freq inside the file is not mapped directly to the filename.  I ened to sort according to the frequency within the filename itself, but freq inside the file content.